# Theano gradient calculation creates float64

Tags: python, neural-network, gpu, theano

I have some standard NN code on Theano with two separate compiled functions.  One that calculates the cost and one that calculates the cost with AdaGrad updates.

For GPU speed, I'm trying to keep everything `float32`.  Problem is that I'm getting a warning that the gradient calculation is creating a `float64`.  In particular, for the following line of code.

```
gradients = TT.grad(lossFn, self.params)
paramUpdates = [(param, param - TT.inv(TT.sqrt(sumGrad)) * grad) for param, grad, sumGrad in zip(self.params, gradients, self.gradSums)]
```

If I comment out the gradient calculation and replace the second line with a placeholder, everything is fine.  Obviously this is a junk update but it helps pinpoint the problem.

```
paramUpdates = [(self.params[0], self.params[0])]
```

For reference, this is the loss function:

```
self.loss = TT.mean(TT.sqr(self.logisticLayer.yHat - TT.cast(self.inputs[1:-1, :], floatX)), acc_dtype=floatX, dtype=floatX)
```

The cost only compiled function is:

```
    self._calculateCost = theano.function(
        inputs=[self.inputs],
        outputs=self.loss,
    )
```

whereas the cost + update function is:

```
    self._calculateCostAndUpdate = theano.function(
        inputs=[self.inputs],
        outputs=self.loss,
        updates=updates
    )
```

**UPDATE**

I pinned down the problem to a LSTM layer.  Here is minimal code

```
class TestLSTMLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputSize, dropout=0.9, inputSize=None, adagradInit=1, forgetGateBias=3, srng=None):
        self.h0 = theano.shared(np.random.randn(outputSize).astype(floatX))

        self.params = [self.h0]

        def _recurrence(hBelow):
            return hBelow

        hOutputs, _ = theano.scan(
            fn=_recurrence,
            outputs_info=self.h0,
            n_steps=inputs.shape[0]
        )
        self.hOutputs = hOutputs

    def getUpdates(self):
        gradients = TT.grad(TT.sum(self.hOutputs), self.params)
        paramUpdates = [(self.params[0], self.params[0])]
        return paramUpdates
```

The problem occurs when I call `getUpdates()` to get gradients (here it is a junk update for example).  I've found that commenting out `gradients = ...` or replacing the `scan()` with something that repeats `h0` to the required shape fixes things.

**UPDATE 2**

Debugging reveals a mess of `int64` in the `scan` function.

```
 |Subtensor{int64::} [@B] <TensorType(float32, matrix)> ''
   |for{cpu,scan_fn} [@C] <TensorType(float32, matrix)> ''
   | |Subtensor{int64} [@D] <TensorType(int64, scalar)> ''
   | | |Shape [@E] <TensorType(int64, vector)> ''
   | | | |<TensorType(float32, matrix)> [@F] <TensorType(float32, matrix)>
   | | |Constant{0} [@G] <int64>
   | |IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:} [@H] <TensorType(float32, matrix)> ''
   |   |Alloc [@I] <TensorType(float32, matrix)> ''
   |   | |TensorConstant{0.0} [@J] <TensorType(float32, scalar)>
   |   | |Elemwise{add,no_inplace} [@K] <TensorType(int64, scalar)> ''
   |   | | |Subtensor{int64} [@D] <TensorType(int64, scalar)> ''
   |   | | |Subtensor{int64} [@L] <TensorType(int64, scalar)> ''
   |   | |   |Shape [@M] <TensorType(int64, vector)> ''
   |   | |   | |Rebroadcast{0} [@N] <TensorType(float32, matrix)> ''
   |   | |   |   |DimShuffle{x,0} [@O] <TensorType(float32, row)> ''
   |   | |   |     |<TensorType(float32, vector)> [@P] <TensorType(float32, vector)>
   |   | |   |Constant{0} [@Q] <int64>
   |   | |Subtensor{int64} [@R] <TensorType(int64, scalar)> ''
   |   |   |Shape [@S] <TensorType(int64, vector)> ''
   |   |   | |Rebroadcast{0} [@N] <TensorType(float32, matrix)> ''
   |   |   |Constant{1} [@T] <int64>
   |   |Rebroadcast{0} [@N] <TensorType(float32, matrix)> ''
   |   |ScalarFromTensor [@U] <int64> ''
   |     |Subtensor{int64} [@L] <TensorType(int64, scalar)> ''
   |Constant{1} [@V] <int64>
```

Comment: What is `self.logisticLayer.yHat`? Is it an int64 by any chance?

Comment: I wish.  `self.logisticLayer.yhat` is a tensor variable defined in another class.  I did a lot of debugging last night and narrowed it down to a call to `scan()`.   I'll post some minimal code in a bit when I get to work.

Comment: Is `floatX` equal to `theano.config.floatX`? Are you 100% certain this has the value `float32`?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain.  I can replace the call to `scan` with TT.repeat(self.h0[None, :], inputs.shape[0], axis=0) and the `float64` warning disappears.

Comment: Is there any update? Using float64 is too slow. I run into the same problem, but I cannot find where I used float64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating to the bleeding edge (latest version on GitHub) version. http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions

Somewhat odd, but a solution nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `theano.printing.debugprint` with `print_type=True` to see what the type of the various components are.

For example,

```
class TestLSTMLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, inputs, outputSize, dropout=0.9, inputSize=None, adagradInit=1, forgetGateBias=3, srng=None):
        self.h0 = theano.shared(np.random.randn(outputSize).astype(floatX))

        self.params = [self.h0]

        def _recurrence(hBelow):
            print 'hBelow', theano.printing.debugprint(hBelow, print_type=True)    
            return hBelow

        print 'h0', theano.printing.debugprint(self.h0, print_type=True)    
        hOutputs, _ = theano.scan(
            fn=_recurrence,
            outputs_info=self.h0,
            n_steps=inputs.shape[0]
        )
        self.hOutputs = hOutputs

    def getUpdates(self):
        print 'sum', theano.printing.debugprint(TT.sum(self.hOutputs), print_type=True)    
        gradients = TT.grad(TT.sum(self.hOutputs), self.params)
        paramUpdates = [(self.params[0], self.params[0])]
        return paramUpdates
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated before, `floatX` is float32 and the print confirms this.

Comment: So `hBelow` and `h0` are both `float32` tensors. What about adding `print 'sum', theano.printing.debugprint(TT.sum(self.hOutputs), print_type=True)` at the start of `getUpdates`?

Comment: Thanks again.  But still no good: `Sum{acc_dtype=float32} [@A] <TensorType(float32, scalar)>`.  But potentially useful debug: